# Xcode will not build Unity3d project, showing multiple errors

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I really need someone to help me. I am trying to build my first Unity3d app ever and transfer it to my iPhone. However, there are no tutorials that I am finding that address the issues that I am facing.

I am trying to build a simple Unity3d project. From what I have seen in the documentation and it various tutorials, it should be as simple as going to build File-> Build Setting -> going to the IOS tab -> clicking build. When it builds out of unity a folder will appear with your project. You then open it and click on the .xproject file that is in it. It will open itself up in Xcode. As long as you have the dependencies down it should be no problem. However this is not the case for me. Here is my step to step process and what I encounter.

[Step 1: Building the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMsJy.jpg)

[Step 2: Opening in Xcode and adding dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A38V9.png)

[Step 3: Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Ha7.png)

I feel like there is something seriously missing. No one else seems to experience this. Someone please give me some insight. Thank you.

Comment: The screenshot does not show which dependencies you are adding.

Comment: by dependencies, I mean my developer ID

Comment: It's possible this is a versioning error. Could you post your unity and xcode versions? You might try making sure everything in xcode is up to date.